# Is it possible to edit wall posts?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, hyperlink

Is it possible to edit wall posts? If so, how can I do this?
Anyhow, I'd like to replace a wall post with modified one.
Wall posts often fail to read meta data which is provided by open graph elements when I post a link to Wall through my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.  According to the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/):

> **Update**
>
> You cannot edit any of the fields in the status message object.

Answer (score 0):

You can [delete](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) wall posts, like you can [delete](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#deleting) most objects. I do not if it possible to edit but you can repost your message.

Comment: I know that I can delete the post and repost it, but I'd like to clear the specific wall post cache and re-crawl the link through api.